# How to easily detect if map is empty or not in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi so I have some variable that take care of whether my button and other widget should be shown or not, I already create a if statement for it and the issue is with detecting whether the map is currently empty or not.

Here's the code:

```
/// Initialize the data
Map data = {};

///If statement 
    if (povStatus == 'pic' && data.isEmpty) {
      showReportEditButton = false;
      showReportWriteButton = true;
      showReportNotif = true;
      showHeaderReport = false;
    } else {
      showReportEditButton = true;
      showReportWriteButton = false;
      showReportNotif = false;
      showHeaderReport = true;
    }
```

Based on the code above, when the data is empty it work just fine and enter the first if. But when I fill the "data" and the map becomes not empty it still enter the first if rather than the else part. What's the reason of this ?

Comment: How you are putting data on map?

Comment: Same question as Yeasin, how do you know you data is "filled". Can you log this and confirm?

Comment: I used the database function to get data from my database

Data = await Database.getMyData(itemId: widget.itemId);

Comment: Yeah, I already tried to print the data and see whether it's empty or not

Comment: Can you include a separate dart file and perform operation and share the error

Comment: I think the problem might be because you don't have setState the new value, remember to setState if you want to rebuild the widget when the value changes

Comment: I have done the set state, so when I tried to print the value of data.isEmpty

print('this is the data: ${powData.isEmpty}');
and the result is this is the data : false

there's a value in my current map

which mean it should have enter the else statement

Comment: Or maybe you change your **povStatus** value somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can read the entries:

```
    Map<String,String> map={};

    if(map.entries.isEmpty){
      //Do something
    }
```

Comment: what is entries ? can you explain it please, thanks before

Comment: `map.entries`makes an iterable out of your map... and this can be checked for its content with `.isEmpty`